# How to install elasticsearch in a docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch in an ubuntu docker container. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04 as elastic_install
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget gnupg apt-transport-https openjdk-8-jdk
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y elasticsearch
```

When I now try to run elasticsearch, it is killed after a few seconds with the following message:

```
root@18c3d6649c1b:/# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
Killed
root@18c3d6649c1b:/# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: line 95:   369 Killed                  exec "$JAVA" "$XSHARE" $ES_JAVA_OPTS -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" -Des.path.conf="$ES_PATH_CONF" -Des.distribution.flavor="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_FLAVOR" -Des.distribution.type="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_TYPE" -Des.bundled_jdk="$ES_BUNDLED_JDK" -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch "$@" <<< "$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
root@18c3d6649c1b:/#
```

How do I install/run elasticsearch correctly? Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: If you can use the standard docker images, I strongly suggest doing that. It's a lot less painful than building your own. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When directly running elasticsearch, the environment variables `ES_PATH_CONFIG` and `ES_JAVA_OPTS` must be defined.

```
elasticuser@c5f357e42e51:/# ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8g -Xmx8g" /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```